# How to deserialise specific field as String from inherited Kotlin data classes with Gson

Tags: kotlin, deserialization, android, gson

I have got my json result as follows. When it comes to default deserlization by Gson, it comes the the id precision issue :

It turns out from :

`{"object":"product","id":15243937043340,"name":"XNZ","tele":"90592","..`

to :

```
 [Product(obj= product, id=1.524393704334E13, name=XNZ...
```

Here is my class :

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

```
data class Product (

        @SerializedName("object")
        val obj: String,
        val id: String,
        val name: String,
        val tele: String, 

...
```

Would you please tell what custom deserialisation to  reserve the precision ? I mean , when i call the attribute id of product class, it should be id=15243937043340 instead id=1.524393704334E13

Comment: try using BigInteger

Comment: It arises from  Invalid BigInteger: 1.524393704334E13

Comment: check this may be helpful https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1084